# How can I Replace special characters

Tags: c#

I've got a string value with a lot of different characters
**I want to:**

- replace  **TAB,ENTER,** with **Space**
- replace Arabic ي  with Persian ی
- replace Arabic ك  with Persian ک
- remove  newlines from both sides of a string
- replace multiple space with one space
- Trim space

The following `Function` is for cleaning data. and it works correctly.
Does anyone have any idea for better performance and less code for maintenance :)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var output = "كgeeks      01$سهيلاطريقي03.       اشك!@!!.ي";
    //output = output.Replace("\u064A", "\u0649");//ي
    output = output.Replace("\u064A", "\u06CC");//replace arabic ي  with persian ی
    output = output.Replace("\u0643", "\u06A9");//replace arabic ك  with persian ک
    output = output.Trim('\r', '\n');//remove  newlines from both sides of a string
    output = output.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", " ");//replace newline with space
    RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
    Regex regex = new Regex("[ ]{2,}", options);//replace multiple space with one space
    output = regex.Replace(output, " ");
    char tab = '\u0009';
    output = output.Replace(tab.ToString(), "");
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Comment: Did you run any benchmarks?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski what do you mean?

Comment: _"because I care about bottleneck"_ So, did you identify your bottleneck?

Comment: No I didn't identify my bottleneck @AhmedAbdelhameed

Comment: @SoheilaTarighi I mean the way, which you identify the bottleneck

Comment: I want to use performance better and less code , Do you any idea? @PavelAnikhouski ,@Ahmed Abdolhameed

Comment: @SoheilaTarighi You might want to read [this article](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/). Also, do some research on bottlenecks and micro-optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor using two lists: one for the trim process and one for the replace process.

```
    var itemsTrimChars = new List<char>()
    {
      '\r',
      '\n'
    };

    var itemsReplaceStrings = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
      { "\n", "" },
      { "\r", " " },
      { "\u064A", "\u06CC" },
      { "\u0643", "\u06A9" },
      { "\u0009", "" }
    }.ToList();
```

Thus they are maintenable tables with the technology you want: as local in this example, declared at the level of a class, using tables in a database,  using disk text files...

Used like that:

```
    itemsTrimChars.ForEach(c => output = output.Trim(c));

    itemsReplaceStrings.ForEach(p => output = output.Replace(p.Key, p.Value));
```

For the regex to replace double spaces, I know nothing about, but if you need to replace other doubled, you can create a third list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by iterating over each character and apply those rules, forming a new output string that is the format you want. It should be faster than all those string.Replace, and Regex.Match.

Use string builder for performance when appending, don't use string += string

Answer (score -2):

First Find Character in your string and then remove it and in the same index add new character

```
private string ReplaceChars(string Source, string Find, string Replace)
{
 int Place = Source.IndexOf(Find);
 string result = Source.Remove(Place, Find.Length).Insert(Place, Replace);
 return result;
}
```

Usage :

```
text= "كgeeks      01$سهيلاطريقي03.       اشك!@!!.ي";
var result =ReplaceChars(text,"ي","ی");
```

Comment: This will replace only one instance of `Find`, I would assume the goal is to replace all of them.

Comment: you are right , but the code for just help , needs more enhancement, i just guide or help answering the question

Comment: If you read the text you will find out that OP actually knows HOW. Question is actually about "any idea for better performance and less code for maintenance". So your answer is nowhere near addressing the actual question.